# siunitx package avoids writing 10^0

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a big table with numbers in scientific notation and I'm using `siunitx` package the problem is that one number is `\SI{8.334e+00}` and I get then `8.334` and I want `8.334x10^0` (the problem exists only with the `0` exponent). Another problem is that I can't put \SI{...} on the last column of the table because I get a compilation error : `! Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition.`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
$E_m$ & $\lambda_1^{\text{tp}}$ & $\lambda_1^{\text{ts}} $ \\ \hline
8.0e7 & \SI{5.8938e+01} & \SI{4.319571e+01} & \SI{3.606297e+01} & 8.514868e+01 \\ \hline
1.0e8 & \SI{5.3398e+01} & \SI{3.583252e+01} & \SI{2.919383e+01} & 8.174273e+01 \\ \hline
2.0e8 & \SI{4.1397e+01} & \SI{1.953532e+01} & \SI{1.495294e+01} & 7.493084e+01 \\ \hline
5.0e8 & \SI{3.2030e+01} & \SI{8.334998e+00} & \SI{6.070005e+00} & 7.084370e+01 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a small but complete example that can be used for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\SI` takes *two* arguments. When you use `\SI{1234} \\` then `\\` is read as second argument. It is not surprising that this leads to errors.

In order to get the zero exponent, use

```
\sisetup{retain-zero-exponent = true}
```

I also suggest to use `S` columns for formatting the numbers – `siunitx` provides lots of stuff for numbers in tables! One advantage: the numbers will be aligned even without `retain-zero-exponent`!

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{retain-zero-exponent}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | S[table-format=1.1e1] | S[table-format=1.4e1] | *3{S[table-format=1.6e1] |} }
  \hline
    {$E_m$} & {$\lambda_1^{\text{tp}}$} & {$\lambda_1^{\text{ts}} $} && \\ \hline
    8.0e7 & 5.8938e+01 & 4.319571e+01 & 3.606297e+01 & 8.514868e+01 \\ \hline
    1.0e8 & 5.3398e+01 & 3.583252e+01 & 2.919383e+01 & 8.174273e+01 \\ \hline
    2.0e8 & 4.1397e+01 & 1.953532e+01 & 1.495294e+01 & 7.493084e+01 \\ \hline
    5.0e8 & 3.2030e+01 & 8.334998e+00 & 6.070005e+00 & 7.084370e+01 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the table is too wide for the text column but that is another problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `retain-zero-exponent` setting for SIunitx. And I tend to use the `\num{}` when displaying numbers with no units.

```
\num[retain-zero-exponent=true]{8.334e+00}
```